# How to Spawn Herobrine without Mods?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Well I have always wanted to see Herobrine. I went into the versions of Minecrft that he isn't removed from but I never seem to spawn him. Can anyone tell me how to spawn him with NO MODS that would be great!

Comment: Herobrine was a joke and did not ever exist.

Answer (score 18):

Herobrine is not in Minecraft (he was never in it).

Source: [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Herobrine)

If you want to see him, you need to mod him in.

Comment: related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urban_legend

Answer (score 1):

## No,

It was actually a myth to spawn Herobrine in your world, but the myth wasn't true. Some say the spawner looked like this:

[image: HerobrineSpawner]

It was said when you lit the netherrack, a lightning hits it with a message saying, "You don't know what you did".

But this spawner doesn't work, neither did it work in any version of Minecraft. Herobrine can't be spawned without mods. Herobrine doesn't exist. it was all a joke. Notch proves it, and so does the game. So the answer is no. It was probally a rumor or a mod.

[Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Herobrine)

Comment: Guys I know why you disliked you think this isn't real, but I said that spawner doesn't work guys!

Comment: I upvoted because funny :)